# How can I get the new value of an HTML input after a click event has modified it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following..

`@ Html.EditorFor ( model = > model.Date )`

A template editor also works in the DateTime type
Clicking on this entry, a calendar is displayed , you select a calendar date , and that date
is the new value of my post. What I need is to validate that the date you select is equal or greater than today.

I tried the onchange event for the EditorFor , but it did not work , Jquery DatePicker property has a MinDate
but added that would mean modifying the operation of all entries with the DateTime data type .

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: Which plugin you're using for `calendar`?

Comment: I'm using the datepicker.

Comment: What `datepicker`? Name of the plugin

Comment: I'm sorry, is the jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: It's not a plugin Tushar, it's in the JQuery library.
So what are you doing exactly?  You're trying to get the new Date from this input?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Datepicker has `onSelect` function which will give you the chosen date that is displayed in date input box! Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aa74R/66/

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  alert(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Question is a bit vague, however I think this should help.
It looks like what you want to do is change the date, based on after you've selected a newDate.  onChange should work.  As far as why it isn't, it could be a matter of code.

If it's a matter of how you've written your code:

```
$('#inputId').on('change', function(){
  var newDate = $(this).val();
});
```

I personally think this might be an easier approach for some, however inefficient as it persistently sets the date every time you leave the field:

```
$('#inputId').on('blur', function(){
  var newDate = $(this).val();
});
```

There are also many other ways to write it.  But I feel like this might have the proper level for you.

Answer (score 0):

Question doesn't seem to have a context with the absence of code.

Since you have tagged jQuery a possible problem might be you are binding the onchange event to the textbox. If this textbox were to be dynamically generated, the onchange event would never be registered. If this is your problem then you could do this-

```
$("body").on("change", "#textBoxId", function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```